# How to add link list to JQuery Mobile Panel?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to add some buttons to j Query Mobile panel that would take me to the video div that is the sibling of home div. I did the following codes but it won't work.

```
  <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-display="push">
    <a href="#video" data-role="button">Videos</a>
    <a href="#home" data-rel="close">Close</a>          
  </div>

  <!-- HEADER -->
  <!-- CONTENT-->
```

Comment: it wont open the video div ..

Comment: but if i add "http://m.facebook.com" instead of "#video" , it sends me to facebook ...

Comment: Add data-ajax=false to anchor.

Comment: I have another issue now:
I clicked on Videos, it took me to the videos page, and when I click "back" button and come back to the "home" page again. the panel button wont work code of panel button -->  <a data-role="button" href="#mypanel" data-icon="grid">Menu</a>

Comment: This is another issue, please post another question with more details on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `data-ajax="false"` attribute to anchor, if you want to scroll to a div within the active page.

```
<div data-role="panel">
  <a href="#video" data-ajax="false">Videos</a>     
</div>
```